# User API and Forgotten Text Message phone number

Tags: okta

I'm using the REST API to obtain a list of users and properties.

http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html

The User object returned by Get Users or List Users contains the secondary email address (in the Profile object) and the forgotten password question (in the Credentials object).  I do not see the forgotten password text message phone number and country.  Is that not available in the User object, and if not is it available anywhere else?

Thanks,

Michael